# Create event listener that will automatically execute callbacks after first fire

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to create a one time event listener that will execute the callbacks immediately after the event is fired the first time.

```
main.js: (loaded first thing)
    $(document).one('plugins_loaded', displayMenu);

plugins.js: (loaded some time after main.js)
    $(document).trigger('plugins_loaded');

checkout.js: (loaded asynchronously or immediately after main.js)
    $(document).one('plugins_loaded', displayCart);
```

I want the `displayCart` to execute immediately, if the `plugins_loaded` event was already triggered before, and if not, then `displayCart` should be called after `displayMenu`, when `plugins_loaded` event fires.

Comment: You could use `.bind` instead of `.one` and then have a variable that stores if the event had been fired before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for

- a Promise, created using a [`$.Deferred`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.Deferred/) or
- a [`$.Callbacks`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.Callbacks/) list with the `once` and `memory` flags.

Store either in some global variable, best in the namespace of your application object. You just need to initialise it once, then you can add callbacks from whereever and whenever you want, and trigger them somewhen later.

You cannot really use a custom event fired on `$(document)`, as past events are not observable.